# Linux Bridge (brctl) not passing the traffic

Tags: linux, ping, bridge

I created the below config:

```
/* Created a Linux bridge and brought it up */
brctl addbr AnaBr4
ifconfig AnaBr4 up

/* Created a tuntap interface and brought it up */
ip tuntap add name Xr1 mode tap
ifconfig Xr1 up

/* Added the tuntap intf to Bridge */
brctl addif AnaBr4 Xr1
```

I attached Xr1 with one of my virtual router. Now I used VMM to instantiate Ubuntu server and attached one NIC to AnaBr4. So the topology is like below:

```
Router(intf1)------(Xr1)(Anabr4)(vnet1)-----(Ens4)Ubuntu
```

I assigned 10.1.1.1/24 fr intf1 and 10.1.1.2/24 for Ens4.

I see that the ARP resolution works fine but I dont see the Ping traffic (or any other traffic).

Tried TCPDUMP and noticed that I am reciving the Ping traffic on brctl but not forwarding out.

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on vnet1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
08:35:30.530193 IP 10.1.1.2 > 10.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9159, seq 986, length 64
08:35:31.558092 IP 10.1.1.2 > 10.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9159, seq 987, length 64
08:35:32.578175 IP 10.1.1.2 > 10.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9159, seq 988, length 64
08:35:33.602173 IP 10.1.1.2 > 10.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 9159, seq 989, length 64
```

showmac appears to be fine, shown below:

```
root@kvmserver:~# brctl showmacs AnaBr4
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 52:46:f8:b8:27:88   no        16.73 /*Router Intf1 MAC */
  2 52:54:00:d8:8e:f8   no         0.32 /* Ubuntu MAC */
  1 aa:0b:51:de:18:7d   yes        0.00
  1 aa:0b:51:de:18:7d   yes        0.00
  2 fe:54:00:d8:8e:f8   yes        0.00
  2 fe:54:00:d8:8e:f8   yes        0.00
root@kvmserver:~#
```

The same config was working for nearly 8 months and I did a reload of the KVM server yesterday after which the same config is not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Hi,
Please find the iptables output below:

```
root@kvmserver:~# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 822K packets, 12G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  101  7429 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
   26  8358 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 3538 packets, 506K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
43713   56M ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
14808  813K ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
    6  1948 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr1 virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 3538  506K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3538  506K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 815K packets, 12G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   26  8592 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3538  506K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3538  506K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
root@kvmserver:~#
```

Hi All,

I think I found the issue. Adding the below to /etc/sysctl.conf file fixed the issue:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Comment: Please post output from `sysctl show net.ipv4.ip_forward`

Comment: Please find the output below:
root@kvmserver:~# sysctl show net.ipv4.ip_forward
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/show: No such file or directory
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
root@kvmserver:~#

Comment: Sorry, should have been just `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, that looks good.

Comment: Please post output from `iptables -vnL` (you can just edit your post and add it to the body).

Comment: Thank you. Updated the output in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the help. The issue is fixed by adding the below to /etc/sysctl.conf file

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Comment: for more informations: [br_netfilter](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html). [ebtables/iptables interaction on a Linux-based bridge](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7) (currently the TLS certificate of the web site is expired)